# How does Rust call ufmodlib DLL on the Windows platform?

Tags: rust

I am on the windows platform, and I want to realize the playback of xm audio files. I looked for a dynamic link library called ufmod. The website has some other related demos, but I don’t know how to implement it on rust. The following is a piece of my code, it does not work.

```
use libloading as lib;
use std::io;
use std::ffi::{CString, c_void};

fn main() {
   let uFMOD = lib::Library::new("ufmod.dll").unwrap();
   unsafe {
      let uFMOD_PlaySong: lib::Symbol<unsafe extern fn(filename: std::ffi::CString, typeoc: i32, 
      dwFlags: i32) -> c_void> = uFMOD.get(b"uFMOD_PlaySong").unwrap();
      uFMOD_PlaySong(CString::new("d:/xm2/obc.xm").unwrap(), 0, 2);
   }
   let mut input = String::new();
   io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
}
```

This is the website link for this library: http://ufmod.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Without any error, i don't know what happened

Comment: When using FFI, you manually have to make sure that all types are correct, the compiler can't help you there. In particular, `std::ffi::CString` isn't FFI-safe and isn't the kind of types you'd expect to find in a non-Rust DLL.

Comment: This is the declaration of a cpp file:'int __stdcall uFMOD_PlaySong(void*, int, int)'
I use rust ffi for matching here

Answer (score 0):

`CString` cannot be passed directly through FFI.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html), you should call `.as_ptr()` on the string and pass the resulting `*const c_char` to the foreign function.

The filename should also be bound at the top of the function, so that it's freed at the end of the program instead of immediately after `uFMOD_PlaySong`.

```
use libloading as lib;
use std::io;
use std::ffi::{CString, c_void};
use std::os::raw::c_char;

fn main() {
   let uFMOD = lib::Library::new("ufmod.dll").unwrap();
   let filename = CString::new("d:/xm2/obc.xm").unwrap();
   unsafe {
      let uFMOD_PlaySong: lib::Symbol<unsafe extern fn(filename: *const char, typeoc: i32, 
      dwFlags: i32) -> c_void> = uFMOD.get(b"uFMOD_PlaySong").unwrap();
      uFMOD_PlaySong(filename.as_ptr(), 0, 2);
   }
   let mut input = String::new();
   io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have fixed some codes. I have encountered some stranger playback problems. It will stop responding immediately after playing. This is my project file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e0NeP7euH2bj4ifHOauiKWtzZusGKPrx/view